# Are medkits consumed on use?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When I use a medkit in battle, does it 'consume' the medkit? I know I can't use it again that battle, but will that same medkit stick around and be available to use in future battles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Medkits remain after use.

They're similar to the Support's Smoke Grenade or the Ghost armor's stealth ability, both of which have limited uses that recharge every mission.

For what it's worth, this is how medkits worked in X-COM as well.

Comment: why did you remove that edit?  its useful to let people know medics can boost the uses per battle up to 3.

Comment: @spartacus Because it should have been a comment, not an edit. Unfortunately, there's no "Edit->Comment" tool.